# Angular" http-in-memory-web-api" can't find module '@angular/http' error

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

Upon compilation, I got this error:

ERROR in node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-backend.service.d.ts(2,75): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
    node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-in-memory-web-api.module.d.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.

In package.json: 
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.0"

I've deleted node_modules -> cleaned npm cache but still the same error

Answer (score 11):

just `npm install @angular/http` . Even though its derpecated. It fixes the problem for the time being

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error. Perhaps because I used `-g` while installing.

```
npm install -g angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

Instead of the instructed

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

Re-installing without

> `-g`

solved the issue for me.

Comment: for me too but I remember to install in project directory

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried to import the latest in-memory web API module but it didn't see http/module, so right from here https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/http-client-backend.service.d.ts just copied the latest code, committed 9 days ago and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me because when I installed the package I was in the parent directory.

Make sure you are in the app directory before installing the package

Answer (score 0):

I had to add dependency to package.json and run npm install -i and that worked for me.